# AngularJS : ngRepeat scope fails in custom directive with isolated scope and ngTransclude

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I made a custom directive ("wizard") based on the JQuery Steps plugin. But im facing problems when using ngRepeat inside my directive. The diretive uses ngTransclude so i can provide the steps content inside the page markup.

Im nowhere near an Angular expert, but what i can find is that it's a bug/freakaccident in Angular where an ngRepeat is used inside a directive with isolated scope and transclusion. Like mentioned here
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874 but i can't seem to get any of the suggestions working :\

The directive looks like this:

```
Directives.wizard = ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        cancel: '&',
        finish: '&',
        stepChanged: '&'
    },
    template: '<div class="wizard" data-ng-transclude></div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        // directive has to be wrapped in order to ngModel on sections to work with transclude: true
        element.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">');

        var opts = {
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            onCanceled: function (event, currentIndex) {
                $scope.cancel();
            },
            onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                $scope.finish();
            },
            onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex) {
                $scope.stepChanged();
            }
        };

        var stepsEl = element.children('.steps-wrapper').steps(opts);

        // wrap 'n compile..
        $compile(stepsEl)($scope);
    }
};}];
```

markup

```
<wizard>
<h3>Title</h3>
<section>
    <p><DG:TextControl runat="server" Key="MineSuccesHistorier.Step1"/></p>
    <input data-ng-model="$parent.newData.Title"></input> <!-- outputs array just fine -->

    <!-- test stuff here -->
    <!-- 1. regular ng-repeat - doesnt work (also tried with $parent.$parent which Batarang says is the correct path -->
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in $parent.newData.Competences">{{item.Title}}</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- 2. try with ng-init - doesnt work -->
    <ul data-ng-init="comp = $parent.newData.Competences">
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in comp">{{item.Title}}</li>
    </ul>
</section>

<h3>Tab</h3>
<section>
    <!-- next wizard tab here -->
</section>
```

How data is set in controller

```
$scope.newData = {
"Competences": [
    {
        "IsSelected": true,
        "Title": "Hest"
    },
    {
        "IsSelected": false,
        "Title": "Kat"
    },
    {
        "IsSelected": true,
        "Title": "Ko"
    },
    {
        "IsSelected": false,
        "Title": "Ged"
    }
],
"Id": "905c1285-d58b-4f65-8df5-52986c70a820",
"Situation": null,
"Title": null}
```

any ideas are much appreciated, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 25/3:**
Added plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/kNl4UEoUa7zU4CgWaGSa?p=preview
When i add isolated scope in the directive, the repeaters stop working. If i leave out the isolated scope, it seems as if the ngRepeats are compiled multiple times.

**UPDATE 2 25/3:**
Added new plunkr with Vinays compiling suggestion - ng-repeat is now compiled only once. But two-way binding with ngModel in controller scope isn't working http://plnkr.co/edit/TR3XxvV4IYI66h4pY5hx?p=preview

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Hi Vinay, yes i just added a plunkr :) When i add isolated scope in the directive, the repeaters stop working. If i leave out the isolated scope, it seems as if the ngRepeats are compiled multiple times.

Comment: Please write a version of your code that isolates this issue. I've been looking at your code for the last couple of minutes and still don't know what the intended output is and what the issue is.

Comment: Also in my browser all three "slides" are initially overlapping. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Content is getting repeated because, `ng-repeat` will compile the contents once and `$compile` will compile it once again.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('wizard', function($timeout, $compile) {   
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="mywizard"></div>', 
    compile: function (tEl) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var stepsEl;

        element.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">');
        element.children('.steps-wrapper').append(tEl.context.innerHTML);
        var content = $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        $timeout(function () {
          element.children('.steps-wrapper').steps(opts);
        })
      }
    }
  };
});
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUEbz1JxvHuGe4Xij0Eu?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for helping out - great to see the repeater is not compiled mutilple times. I knew what the problem was, but not how to solve it. The only thing im missing now is the two-way binding so im able to update my data-model in the controller scope and using an isolated scope. I've made a plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/TR3XxvV4IYI66h4pY5hx?p=preview that shows the issue. Lastname is printed with with {{lastname}}, but the input box with ng-model="firstname" isnt displaying nor updating. Any ideas?

Comment: When you specify isolateScope it breaks the chain from the controller scope. Instead of isolateScope try `scope:true`. Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lHQyXyN0yAzIob67X21X?p=preview